# Nbandroid - Clicking run in netbeans doesn't re-compile code

Tags: android, netbeans, emulation

It used to be that after making changes in my code, I could simply click run in netbeans and the updates would be evident in the android emulator.  Now, for some reason, I have to click "Clean and build" first, then run.  If I simply click run, the version from the most recent compile will be pushed the the emulator.  I have no idea what changed.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing with Netbeans 7.2 without the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. Please file a bug against the plugin. There is a guide for this at http://www.nbandroid.org/p/contacts.html

It will be good to know plugin version, Android SDK version and NetBeans version. In addition to that you can take a look at the output from Ant verbose build to see if the .apk file deployed to emulator is really rebuilt (there is a button on the left bar of output window that leads you to a page where you can adjust Ant settings to print this verbose output).